# Property with getter always returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, getter-setter

This is blowing my mind. I have this class with the following properties:

```
public IEnumerable<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }

public int TotalQuestions
{
    get
    {
        return Questions.Count();
    }
}

public int TotalCorrect
{
    get
    {
        return Questions.Count( x => x.Correct );
    }
}

public int Score
{
    get
    {
        return ( TotalCorrect / TotalQuestions ) * 100;
    }
}
```

Here's how I create the model in the controller:

```
var model = new QuizModel
    {
        Questions = new List<QuestionModel>
            {
                new QuestionModel
                    {
                        Correct = true
                    },
                new QuestionModel
                    {
                        Correct = false
                    }
            }
    };
```

TotalQuestions is equal to 2. TotalCorrect is equal to 1. But Score is always 0.

I thought maybe Score was set before the other properties were set, so I tried this:

```
public int Score()
{
    return ( TotalCorrect / TotalQuestions ) * 100;
}
```

I figured this would work because by the time I called Score() in the view the other properties would be set for sure. But it just returns 0.

I also tried changing the IEnumerable to an IList. No luck there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This is blowing my mind.

Dude. Chill. It's all good.

> TotalQuestions is equal to 2. TotalCorrect is equal to 1. But Score is always 0.

Well, do the math yourself. What integer is closest to 1 / 2, rounding towards zero?  Obviously zero. What is zero multiplied by 100? Obviously zero. So the answer is zero.

The problem is that *you're using all-integer arithmetic*. Integer division rounds off to the nearest integer which is always zero in your scenario -- unless the number of correct answers exactly equals the total number of questions, in which case it is one.

To fix the problem here are two techniques,

First, you could multiply by 100 *first* and then do the division.

```
return ( 100 * TotalCorrect )  / TotalQuestions;
```

Now we multiply 100 by 1, get 100, divide that by 2, get 50, done.

Or you could cast one of the integers to a decimal, do the computation in decimals, and then cast it back to integer at the end:

```
public int Score()
{
    return (int)(( (decimal)TotalCorrect / TotalQuestions ) * 100);
}
```

Now we convert 1 to 1.0m, divide by 2 to get 0.5m, and multiply by 100 to get 50.0m.  Then convert that to int to get 50.

**Note**: use *decimal* and not *double*. You are less likely to run into strange rounding errors if you do. Remember, decimal accurately represents fractions where the denominator contains any combination of powers of two and five; double only accurately represents fractions where the denominator is a power of two.

Should you ever wish to allow a non-integer score, the latter algorithm is probably better.

Comment: I thought I had some kind of fundamental misunderstanding of how getters and setters work. Turns out it was my basic math skills that needed work!

Comment: @davidkennedy85: Someone asks this almost every day. It's a very common "gotcha".

Comment: I'm sure you're right, and sorry for the duplicate. But how would you go about searching for such a thing? "c# getter returns 0" returns a million questions that are unrelated. "c# getter returns 0 when it's an int and it's based on two other properties that are also int" is also pretty useless...

Comment: @davidkennedy85 You're right about that, but that's about the time you actually try the code in the getter isolated with your test values. Then you would have seen that the getter itself was not the problem.

Comment: @davidkennedy85: It's a hard one to search for because if you knew to look for "integer division rounds to zero" or some such thing, you'd already know what the problem was.

Answer (score 4):

Your dividing an integer by an integer, so the result is an integer.  Since the result is 0.5, as an integer that is 0.

Just cast either operand to a `double` (or `decimal`) first:

```
( TotalCorrect / (double)TotalQuestions ) * 100;
```

Comment: Don't forget to cast back to integer.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing integers, and result is getting truncated to zero. Convert the first to float or double.

```
public int Score()
{
    return (int)(((float)TotalCorrect / TotalQuestions ) * 100);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to cast back to integer.